# How to start a Service when the Android application is started?

Tags: android, android-service, android-manifest, android-lifecycle

I have a background `Service`. I want its life cycle to be independent of that of the application's `Activity`s.

And yes, I know I have to manually shut the service down manually as a part of the application logic.

Comment: so what do you have problems with?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How to start a Started Service together with the first activity of the Application?

Call `startService(intent)` in the `onCreate()` method of the first `Activity`.

> I have a background service. I want its life cycle to be independent of the application activities.

The best way to do that is to create a `PendingIntent` for a `Service` and register it with the `AlarmManager`:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, LocationService.class);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(this, 1, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);        
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
am.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,0,60*60*1000, pi);  /* start Service every hour. */
```

This will ensure that the `Service` is periodically started at regular intervals, independent of whether the user has brought the app to the foreground or not.

> How to start a Service when the Android application is started?

You can start the `Service` automatically on application start by extending the [`Application`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) class:

```
public class MyApp extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        startService(new Intent(this, NetworkService.class));
    }

}
```

and modify the `application` tag in your `manifest` with

```
<application 
    android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:name="com.mycompanydomain.MyApp">
```

This works because the `Application` class is one of the first entities to be created when an app launches. This will start the `Service` irrespective of what the launch `Activity` is.

Comment: Thanks Y.S. Starting the service on the first activity is what I do for the moment. I am looking for another way, for example: respond to the MAIN action somehow. 

The scenario is all my activities use the service, providing the interface for that service. The service is a network IO related, so it must stay alive.

Comment: so what exactly is the problem that you are facing ? what are you unable to achieve here ?

Comment: It is a matter of application design. It would be more convenient if we can declare which service to boot the same way we declare which activity to load, in the manifest. For now, I designate an activity as the entry point of the application, and load the service there. But what if I choose another activity to be the entry point? Cut-and-paste does not seem clean enough for me.